# Xpath working for selenium python not working in selenium java

Tags: java, python, selenium, xpath, driver

**The html body is like :**

**Java selenium code (error):**

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='password_old']")));
```

**error message:**

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
> waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:
> //input[@id='password_old']

**python selenium code (working correctly):**

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='password_old']")))
myElem.send_keys("yes sure")
```

Comment: Well I don't see any issue with Java code. Try replacing `visibilityOfElementLocated` to `presence_of_element_located` and you are not sending anything also

Comment: The code is not working because the element was present but not visible. As correctly pointed by @cruisepandey the presenceOfElementLocated will just check elements presence on the page while the visibilityOfElementLocated has to check the presence and whether is element visible.